# Can't debug ASP.NET application stored in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I have a question regarding **IIS (version 7.5) and ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4)** . I am trying to debug ASP.NET web application which is stored on IIS. Now, I have done this in past and everytime it worked perfectly.

But now when I try to do same, **Visual Studio 2010** always gives me error, **"unable to start debugging on the web server. the iis worker process for the launched URL is not currently running" ...** even the application I had created in past (& stored in IIS) can't debug using Visual Studio. But all applications (new & old) can be accessed if I type their path in Browser, and they work fine too.

I did search on internet about my problem and I found many posts, but almost every post talks about activating **Windows Authentication** in IIS for the application in question. But, I am using Windows 7 home premium and the IIS shipped with this version doesn't support option for Windows Authentication. Also, if this is the only reason then why my old applications were working just fine till now without this Authentication method?? I found [MSDN help about this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx) but it is not much helpful to me. I also checked APPLICATION POOL selection in IIS and my Application (both are using V.4.XX.XXX)... I have also checked **BINDING** , which is *:80 to Default Website, that means all requests to port 80 will be directed to default website (where my all applications reside)

As a side note, I have SharePoint Server 2010 installed. Which has its own website (which I have disabled while debugging) ...

I think there is something is changed in my IIS configuration, but I cant figure out what it is. And I am sure that it has something to do with SharePoint installation (may be because of more than one website on IIS for same port ??). Because I am using IIS for first time after installing SharePoint and I am having this error.

I will really appreciate if any one has answer ...

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: As I suspected ... having more than one site in IIS was root cause of trouble, Once I uninstalled Sharepoint Server 2010 and its web sites from IIS, my Visual Studio 2010 debugger was able to "Auto-Attach" w3wp.exe process while debugging any application ... ( I really don't see any reason that even after disabling all other websites why still it was giving me error at first place ?? )

I know its not a solution, because I have to remove Sharepoint Server ... but at present its more important for me to work on that application then Sharepoint Server.

But I am still open for any suggestions which might help me to run both together ....

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Best practice for SharePoint is to run it in a VM, which could mean you avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Bug fix for this issue in the Microsoft's Connect site.

.

Is it with .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010 , if yes , then check http://www.ginktage.com/2010/08/fix-for-visual-studio-2010-hangs-when-debugging-asp-net-3-5-web-application/ for information